# SQLite Count of Values in 1 Column and Group By ID

Tags: sqlite, count

I've been struggling to get the count of the values of my table, so far it does not give me the expected output. I've tried every combination of Count and Group By and nothing worked.

This is the snippet of my table

```
=========================
id | budget_id | type
=========================
1  | 1         | expenses
2  | 1         | expenses
3  | 1         | savings
4  | 1         | expenses
5  | 1         | expenses
6  | null      | savings
7  | 1         | savings
8  | 2         | expenses
9  | 2         | savings
```

So I want to count to total number of expenses and savings and group it by budget_id

**The expected output must be like this (null value in budget_id must be ignored, hence the '2' in savings for budget_id = 1):**

```
=============================================
budget_id | savings         | expenses
=============================================
1         | 2               | 4
2         | 1               | 1
```

But the output is like this:

```
=============================================
budget_id | savings         | expenses
=============================================
null      | 1               | 1
1         | 2               | 2
1         | 4               | 4
2         | 1               | 1
2         | 1               | 1
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT budget_id, count(CASE type WHEN 'savings' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) savings, count(CASE type WHEN 'expenses' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) expenses
from expenses_savings
group by budget_id, type
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include `type` into the `group by`, so you don't have multiple results for the same budget.

Use `sum` instead of `count` to count the different occurrences.

Explicitly exclude the rows where budget is null.

```
SELECT 
    budget_id, 
    sum(CASE type WHEN 'savings' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) number_of_saved, 
    sum(CASE type WHEN 'expenses' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) number_of_spent 
from expenses_savings 
where budget_id is not null
group by budget_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem! Chosen as accepted answer!

Comment: Nice answer.  It looks like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Change `count` to `sum`, and aggregate only by the `budget_id`:

```
SELECT
    budget_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'savings'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) number_of_saved,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'expenses' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) number_of_spent
FROM expenses_savings
GROUP BY budget_id
```

Besides using the wrong grouping, the problem with using `COUNT` is that it actually counts both zero and one.  If you wanted to use `COUNT` then you could try the following query:

```
SELECT
    budget_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'savings'  THEN 1 END) number_of_saved,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'expenses' THEN 1 END) number_of_spent
FROM expenses_savings
GROUP BY budget_id
```

Now for non matching types the value being counted would be `NULL` (which is the default `ELSE` value in a `CASE` expression), and therefore would be ignored by the count.